# getting table to return empty rows in R

Tags: r

If I have

```
> pred <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
> actual <-c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
> table(Predictions = pred, TrueLabels = actual)
           TrueLabels
Predictions 0 1
          0 3 2
          1 2 3
>
```

then two rows are returned, one for predictions of false, one for predictions of true. Is there any way to get table to return two rows (one of them empty) when the predictions are all one or the other?

```
> pred <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
> actual <-c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
> table(Predictions = pred, TrueLabels = actual)
           TrueLabels
Predictions 0 1
          0 5 5
>
```

I'd like it to return

```
           TrueLabels
Predictions 0 1
          0 5 5
          1 0 0
>
```

instead, so that when I look up my TN/FP etc for calculating specificity and sensitivity, that I don't have to check whether the second row exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to convert it to `factor` with `levels` specified so that the particular combination will not be dropped

```
table(Predictions = factor(pred, levels = 0:1), TrueLabels = factor(actual, levels = 0:1))
#        TrueLabels
#Predictions 0 1
#          0 5 5
#          1 0 0
```